# java - Allow extending static method in sub classes

Tags: java, junit, java-8

Using JUnit all my runner classes implement a method that is annotated with

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {}
```

There is a lot of mutual code.

I want to create a base runner that will hold all the base code and will allow sub classes to add more features.

This is all static. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider your design. The `@BeforeClass` annotation is intended to specify code that has to run *exactly once* for all tests. If you repeat the same code in multiple `static` methods annotated with `@BeforeClass`, in other words, execute the same action multiple times, it suggests that it is not the `@BeforeClass` semantic that you want.

Maybe you just want instance methods annotated with `@Before`

Otherwise, if it’s really about single time actions, just put a `static` method with the `@BeforeClass` annotation into the base class, and you’re done. The initialization of the subclass implies the initialization of the base class. The initialization of the base class will happen exactly once for *all* subclasses but that is what `@BeforeClass` is all about. As said, if you want an initialization once per subclass or once per test, it’s more likely that `@Before` is the feature you want.

Note further, that you *can* have code in `static` methods in a base class which is only executed when subclasses invoke it. Just place the code into a method *without* the `@BeforeClass` annotation. Then, methods in subclasses, having the annotation or not, may invoke the method of the base class. There is no need for an override relationship here.

Answer (score 0):

As said; there is no "overriding" for static; and of course: **static** is by itself ... very often an indication for "design improvement required". Everybody who is writing serious unit tests knows that static things can make unit testing a night-mare. So we avoid **static** in our production code. But then, in our testing code, we just use it?!

And going one step further: some people claim that **inheritance** is not a good answer to "i have a lot of common code within my unit tests".

See [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the common code to a rule and reuse that rule in every test: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules